# Where can i find the build.gradle file for admob

Tags: android, admob, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to setup an admob by following the example. I have installed the google play service. In my project, I can't see a file called build.gradle.

> You should have a project-level build.gradle file and an application-level build.gradle file

How do i get those file

I even go under eclipse sdk folder but couldn't find the google play service anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

build.gradle is a file used by [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html). You should probably [migrate](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) your Eclipse project to an Android Studio one.

Instructions on how to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio:

> 1.Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin (you must have version 22.0 or higher).
>
> 2.In Eclipse, select File > Export.
>
> 3.In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.
>
> 4.Select the project you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish.
>
> Your selected project remains in the same location but now contains a
> build.gradle file and is ready for Android Studio.

After you finished installing [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) and exporting your project, continue onto the following steps

> 1.In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
>
> 2.Click Import Project.
>
> 3.Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, select the build.gradle file and click OK.
>
> 4.In the following dialog, leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK. (You do not need to specify the Gradle home.)

Now you will find the build.gradle file in your project's root directory.

To install Google Play Services Library:

> ( 1 ) Download Google Play Services SDK
>
> Lunch Android SDK Manager
>
> In the SDK Manager window Scroll down and expand Extras folder Select
> Google Play services Click Install Package
>
> ( 2 ) Import the Library into Workspace
>
> Now you need to import Google Play services library into your app
> current workspace.
>
> File >> Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace,
> and browse to the copy of the library project to import it. The Google
> Play services SDK is saved in your Android SDK environment at
> /extras/google/google_play_services/.
>
> Click Finish
>
> ( 3 ) Add Google Play services to Your App
>
> Right-click your App project Select Properties In the Properties
> window select Android Under the Library section click Add Select
> google-play-services-lib Click OK

Instruction found [here](http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/).

Comment: Ok i see. If i wanted to keep using eclipse, how do i find the google play service library. I saw from internet saying: it was located in the sdk folder in the eclipse but i can't find it.

Comment: File >> Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse to the copy of the library project to import it. The Google Play services SDK is saved in your Android SDK environment at <android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/. Once you've found it hit finish. Then 
    Right-click your App project
    Select Properties
    In the Properties window select Android
    Under the Library section click Add
    Select google-play-services-lib
    Click OK.
Found [here](http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/)

Comment: C:\...\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\extras is this the path. The adt-bundle folder is where my eclipse situated. in this extras folder i can't find the google folder

Comment: In the answer I've left more detailed instructions on how to install and download them. A set of instructions that may be easier for you to follow can be found [Here](http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/)

Comment: Ok i think i found the folder... I know how to install it but don't know where the folder is. But thanks.

Comment: Once you download the Google Play Services from the Android SDK Manager you should be able to find the folder for it in the specified location.